# Puppet Dashboard:Dependency issue on RHEL 6

Tags: rubygems, rake, puppet

I have open source puppet. now while installing puppet dashboard this is what i get:

```
[root@ip-x-x-x-x /]# yum --enablerepo=puppetlabs install puppet-dashboard

Error: Package: puppet-dashboard-1.2.23-1.el6.noarch (puppetlabs)
           Requires: rubygem(rake)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I looked for the option to install rake but having trouble.can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your machine is subscribed to the `rhel-6-server-optional-rpms` repository, using subscription-manager or rhn.